# How can I disable a div with onclick function if screensize is 600 or less

Tags: javascript, html, media-queries

Hi I have a div next to a calendar, which displays the event of the date selected. Now when the screen size is 600 or less. The calendar div need to replace with the events div how do I perform this action.

Comment: What have you tried? (Show us your code)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you yo use CSS instead of JS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    div.className {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 600px)" );

if(mq.matches){
// Do this
}
```

Good Reference
https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/